# Wired connection keeps disconnecting on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers

I'm working with Ubuntu 14.04 and the wired connection keeps disconnecting. The output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` is the following

```
    00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:05d4]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1533] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:05d4]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
```

I tried to look to the other answers in the forum but I didn't find any with the same drivers. Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens to the network connection exactly? Do you have it working for a while and the disconnects, or is always disconnecting or maybe when you do certain action it disconnects?

Comment: It works for a while and after 5/10 minutes the connection stops to work; in order to restart the connection I have to disconnect it and reconnect it

Comment: Open a terminal window, and type `journalctl --follow`, or wait until it disconnects and type `journalctl --since="-10 minutes"` to see the log messages. Read these messages carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using

sudo ./check_network_2

that checks the connection and re-establishes the connection if it drops out

Comment: Where did you get that `check_network_2`?